# Playing sound create lag for sprite's animation

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I created android live wallpaper application using AndEngine library. The wallpaper has a swing animation with sound.

The problem is everytime the swinging sound plays, the swing animation become lagged for few milliseconds.

I want to know is there a solution for this? I had tried by creating a thread for playing the sound, but the result was still lagged too.

The code is like this...

```
public class TreeSwingSprite extends AnimatedSprite 
    implements IAnimationListener, IEntityModifierListener {

    ...
    private Sound swingSound;

    // this event happened when user touch the Sprite on screen
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
            ...

            long[] frameDuration = new long[] {                                            
                50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
                ...
            };

            final int[] frame = {                             
                10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
                ...
            };

            animate(frameDuration, frame, 0, this); // this code execute the animation of the Sprite

            // play the sound
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (swingSound != null) swingSound.play();
                }
            }).start();

    }
}
```

If you don't know AndEngine, pure openGL ES solution is okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the cause of lag is the particular device doesn't have strong hardware support, probably the processor. I know that because when I tried with other device, it run fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to play a Sound on a new Thread!